# Different colours for geom_polygon in radar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, fill, radar-chart

How can I fill the geom_polygon with different colours and not only with #3232ff? Any help is much appreciated! I've tried to set "fill" to the cbPalette variable but that does not seem to work, unfortunately?

This is my data:

```
C1,Criteria 1,1
C2,Criteria 1,6
C3,Criteria 1,4
C4,Criteria 1,4
C1,Criteria 2,4
C2,Criteria 2,2
C3,Criteria 2,6
C4,Criteria 2,2
C2,Criteria 3,6
C3,Criteria 3,6
C3,Criteria 3,6
C4,Criteria 3,6
C1,Criteria 4,4
C2,Criteria 4,6
C3,Criteria 4,2
C4,Criteria 4,6
C1,Criteria 5,6
C2,Criteria 5,1
C3,Criteria 5,6
C4,Criteria 5,4
C1,Criteria 6,4
C2,Criteria 6,6
C3,Criteria 6,4
C4,Criteria 6,6
C1,Criteria 7,6
C2,Criteria 7,4
C3,Criteria 7,4
C4,Criteria 7,6
C1,Criteria 8,6
C2,Criteria 8,2
C3,Criteria 8,2
C4,Criteria 8,4
```

This is my code:

```
dataset = read.csv("data.csv", header=FALSE, dec=",") 
colnames(dataset) = c("type", "variable", "value")
dataset$value = as.numeric(dataset$value)

dataset$variable <- factor(dataset$variable, levels = rev(dataset$variable), ordered=TRUE)

 # Radar function ------------------------------------------------------------
 coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1) {theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
   r <- if (theta == "x")
"y"
  else "x"
   ggproto("CordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start, direction = sign(direction), is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)}


     # Radar plot ------------------------------------------------------------
     radar <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(group = type, color = type), fill="#3232ff", size = 1, alpha=0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(group = type, color = type), size = 1) +
  #  ggtitle("Plot title") +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") +
  ylim(1,10) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,6), breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), expand=c(0,2)) + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  coord_radar() +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=4, byrow=TRUE), shape=guide_legend(nrow=1, byrow=TRUE)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=cbPalette) + 
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    legend.key = element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_rect(color="#ffffff", fill="transparent"), ### neu check !!!
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white", size = 0.1, linetype = "solid"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid', colour = "#dddddd")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `fill` parameter from your `geom_polygon` call, and add `fill = type` to the `aes()` portion (either in the main `ggplot` call or in `geom_polygon`.

Comment: Great, that does it! So in the end it looks like this `radar <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = variable, y = value, group=type, color=type,fill=type)) +` and `geom_polygon(aes(group = type, color = type), size = 1, alpha=0.2) `

Comment: But actually that gives me a weird order of colours. The outer line and the shape don't match. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Add a `scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)` to your ggplot so that the values match the `scale_color_manual()`.

Comment: That works! Fantastic ... thank you very much!